# Laravel 5.7+, How to use helper functions within Blade templates smartly

Tags: laravel-5, helper, laravel-facade

Since **Laravel 5.7**, the majority of global [Helper](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#available-methods) functions (specifically the ones related with "*Arrays & Objects*" and "*Strings*") are now based on **Facades** (using `Illuminate\Support\Str` and `Illuminate\Support\Arr` classes) instead of being defined as "*normal*" helper functions, as they were before 5.7 (see difference with previous Laravel 5.6 [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#available-methods)).

**Does it really mean that we are not allowed to use them anymore directly within our Blade views?** If we do, they have to be obviously prefixed with its full path in any case, resulting in a dirtier Blade views...
Is not this change counter-productive?

**EDIT**:

- Made some googling and found [this](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-8-deprecates-string-and-array-helpers) article that confirms the situation.
- Also, I have seen that in 5.8.17 it is planned to include Arr and Str aliases by default within config/app.php ([link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/590ae1703103011cc9d1d6abd924261748d7b8ac)).

In the meanwhile, I proceed to register Arr and Str aliases in my config/app.php config file to avoid the full path issue.

Thanks

Comment: if someone is still interested, this is how you register them as aliases https://paulund.co.uk/upgrading-laravel-6-using-arr-and-str-in-blade-files